# Build Crosswalk Stuck at downloading library

Tags: ionic-framework, crosswalk

I wanted to add crosswalk browser support to my existing project, so I run the following command:
ionic browser add crosswalk@14.43.343.23

But when I run ionic build android
it's stuck at this message in the cli:

> Download https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org /xwalk/xwalk_core_library/14.43.343.25/xwalk_core_library-14.43.343.25.aar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first few attempts the message just stuck at the download message. When I did a restart and tried it, it worked. Build successful. This may help others like me who will get worried if build doesn't complete.